# Glue sticks designed for raw wood

Tags: adhesive

I have some glue sticks that I have been using. I did not keep the packaging.

My glue gun is adjustable to a range
of temperatures.

My gun is set to 180 degrees C.

I have been using it on raw wood for quite a while and am happy with the results.

But I am not sure if I am getting the strongest bond possible.

Is there a way to tell if my glue sticks are for wood?

Thanks.

Comment: Any make/model/type marked on the glue sticks?

Comment: I do not understand what you are saying? @RetiredATC

Comment: "But I am not sure if I am getting the strongest bond possible." I saw a glue test a couple of years ago on wood and Titebond II was the strongest. Things may have changed since then.

Comment: My post is about hot glue sticks, but your comment does provide some good info on liquid glues. @RetiredATC

Comment: Raw wood....as opposed to cooked wood?

Comment: What is cooked wood? @Steve Wellens

Comment: Note that hot glue, because it sits on the surface rather than soaking in, is a relatively week adhesive. In fact it's often used specifically for joints that are intended to be temporary, either because you plan to disassemble again or because they just have to hold until some other fastening mechanism is applied. If you need strength, consider a different adhesive.

Comment: @fixit7 What is raw wood?   Wood that hasn't been cooked?

Comment: I have found that hot glue is good for things that are not moved much or do not have any stress put on the joint. @keshlam

Answer (score 1):

As long the glue is molten you are getting good bond.

This will avoid getting cold spots (bad adhesion)

However the 180 C will depend on glue type used.

Comment: Glue is molten is necessary, but doesn't tell you if it is a "great bond" - that will depend on the type of glue and type of wood, surface preparation, etc.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact given the fact that the surfaces are prepared correctly, one needs a steady hand, good eye and proper timing